# What's the correct Flow type pattern when calling different functions depending on the type of a variable?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm kind of new to Flow and changing from "do whatever you like with the code" style in javascript to the more strict typing Flow forces you is a pain sometimes.

I have a class with a function returning the following:

```js
const { id: idParam, params } = this.config[tag];
return params.map((param: string | ObjectConfigParam) => {
  const paramType = typeof param;
  let ret = { id: element.id, tag, position };
  if (paramType === 'string') {
    ret = { ...ret, ...this.resolveStringParam(element, param) };
  } else if (paramType === 'object') {
    ret = { ...ret, ...this.resolveObjectParam(element, param) };
  }
  return ret;
})
```

As `params` can be two different things (a simple `string` or a more complex `ObjectConfigParam`) I've defined to different functions to process them. The signature of the functions are:

`resolveStringParam(element: any, param: string): Field`

`resolveObjectParam(element: any, param: ObjectConfigParam): Field`

Running the flow checker reports the following error:
`Cannot call this.resolveStringParam with param bound to param because ObjectConfigParam [1] is incompatible with string [2].`
for the first call and
`Cannot call this.resolveObjectParam with param bound to param because string [1] is incompatible with ObjectConfigParam [2].`
for the second one.

Comment: A self-contained version of this in flow.org/try would make it a lot easier for people to answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place `typeof param` inside the `if` condition.
By the way, you don't need the second `if`.

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDyARgFZ4DGGAwnAHZQCWA5gAoCGATuwLZgC8YAN5gAznB54AauxgBXPAC4xGTozrMwAXwDc6VFDl0qjemE55xMAG54AyqvVsuvABSjVyj2o0BKYVoGRiZmFla2JORUHNw8rnBkypGUNPRMzrH+QoGoFPQeYAAeAmCuOC48Xo4aYAA+RGQptAwsMbz+-AB8wqhgYIxQpdj4cIPlsQL8ggDk3k7TWb195pZwNvbVGW7j7Xp9WmB4MKIEQkt9YWsRjdEVZRW+e9qoWkA

```
type ObjectConfigParam = { someValue: string };

function resolveStringParam(str: string) {}
function resolveObjectParam(obj: ObjectConfigParam) {}

const x = (param: string | ObjectConfigParam) => {
  if (typeof param === 'string') {
    resolveStringParam(param);
  } else {
    resolveObjectParam(param);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see. I started to realize about this with `null` values as well. I added the second if for to be more explicit, but I guess we already have the type definition for that.